# ANDROID-- How to find position of mobile relative to the world around it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graph, android-sensors

**Background:**

I am currently developing a Web-Based 3D multi-player motion sensor console game (Air Table Tennis). Mobile is acting as a racket for game, Sensor data (gyroscope,accelerator,rotation-vectors) is used rotate racket. Mobile transmit sensor data to game engine(BabylonJS,NodeJS,SocketIO) where on real time I map those values.

**Problem:**

> I want when user(holding mobile) moves in any direction my racket on game 
>   screen will also move in that particular direction.

For this i have studied azimuth values,velocity-graphs and Google Project Tango(Tango is using Computer Vision which in my case can not be implemented) but I am not getting anywhere. If someone suggests me anything it'll be highly appreciated!

Comment: it will be more helpful if you provide information about the engine you are going to use

Comment: I am using BabylonJS as my game engine, with nodeJS & Socket.IO for mobile game communication

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this section here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords

Just keep in mind that not all devices have gyroscopes or magnetometers, so getting phone positions relative to the earth would be impossible on such devices.